# Avoid spacing above wrapfigure

Tags: wrapfigure

Why does the `wrapfigure` environment not allow for continuation of the sentence, but places white text above the figure instead? The picture is illustrating my problem.

[image]

By adding `\fbox`, I get the following result:
[image]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,danish,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum

    \begin{wrapfigure}[10]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{FunFun}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Side_product_Furan.jpg}
    \label{Carbenoid}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \noindent
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Do you see that the second `\lipsum` dosn't follow the first?

Comment: Maybe it comes from white space at the top of the figure. You can check that inserting your figure in a `\fbox`.

Comment: Where is that command supposed to go? Before or after \begin{wrapfigure} ?

Comment: After. If you use `\includegraphics`, it would be `\fbox{\includegraphics{my graphic file}}`.

Comment: you haven't shown your code so that makes it very hard to guess what in the code is forcing a paragraph break, it looks like you are forcing a break after  `allowing` but impossible to say

Comment: You CAN insert wrapfigure into the middle a a paragraph, but it has to be at a line break.

Comment: The blank line after the first `\lipsum` ensures a paragraph break. `lipsum` also ensures a paragraph break, I think. So you have a break here without the `wrapfigure`.

Comment: I replaced the \lipsum with normal writing to avoid the paragraph break, however, the problem is the same.

Comment: The output that you show is not from the code you show, please change them to match. Also no one can use `Side_product_Furan.jpg` please use `example-image` (which is a test image available for this use) or just use `\rule` as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have given no clues about your input, but it looks like you have the first form, with a paragraph break mid-sentence, and you want the second form without a paragraph break after "allowing"

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

zzzzz zzzz zzz zzz zzz zz zzzzzz
zzzzz zzzz zzz zzz zzz zz zzzzzz
zzzzz zzzz 
character thus allowing

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}
\caption{Carbenoid of something}
\end{wrapfigure}
C-H into electron rich systems such as olefins and 
alkynes. Given the oribital discussion above, the
carbene would be expected to react in the singlet
state and therefore in a concerted fashion.

aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa
aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa

\bigskip


\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
  \rule{3cm}{3cm}
\caption{Carbenoid of something}
\end{wrapfigure}
zzzzz zzzz zzz zzz zzz zz zzzzzz
zzzzz zzzz zzz zzz zzz zz zzzzzz
zzzzz zzzz 
character thus allowing
C-H into electron rich systems such as olefins and 
alkynes. Given the oribital discussion above, the
carbene would be expected to react in the singlet
state and therefore in a concerted fashion.

aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa
aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa

\end{document}
```